# network connector for active mq add all topic names that follow an expression

Tags: activemq-classic, network-connection

I want to connect all topics that follow some string pattern like : testTopics*.raw

I tried doing the following:

```
<networkConnectors>
      <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://localhost:62616)"
         name="bridge"
         conduitSubscriptions="true"
         decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="false"
         destinationFilter="NO_DESTINATION">
        <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
            <topic physicalName="testTopics*.raw"/>
        </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
      </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

But this didnt work. I tried looking online but havent been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html) in destination names can only be used between seperators (the `.` character). So while you can't do `testTopics*.raw` you can do `testTopics.*.raw`, which will match topics with names like `testTopics.foo.raw`.`

Comment: Yep I was just about to answer this cause i figured it out haha
Thanks for the help tho!